# Get rid of "unused" sessions in session switcher

Tags: lightdm, kde4, kde5

As shown in the screenshot below, whenever I enter the session switcher (it doesn't matter if it's via <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> (KRunner), the lock screen, etc.), I see an "Unused" entry for each VT that has an X session running in it.

[image: KRunner showing "unused" sessions]

This problem has persisted since Ubuntu 14.04 and followed me from LightDM to SDDM (and KDE4 to KDE5). How do I make the extra entries go away?