# "Unused" sessions in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu

In the session switcher, in addition to real sessions (with usernames) and the option to add a new session, I see several ones labeled "unused".  These seem to materialize over time, since they are not there upon fresh reboot.  Why are they there and how do I get rid of them?

Comment: Looks like [you're not alone](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/comments/8g8cdk/switch_user_actually_logs_out/) at any rate.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/1121290/248158 as well.

Comment: @DKBose that's by the same user; I assume they're familiar with it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug, which is [reported on Launch Pad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sddm/+bug/1462615).

For the moment, it remains unclear what exactly is going on there, but from what Tony wrote on the launchpad page, it seems as though Kubuntu auto-generates two sessions per real user, of which only one gets removed when you kill the session.  This accounts for a gradually accumulation over time.

Comment: And there's [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/655552/248158) as well.